# Is it OK to instantiate OnClickListeners in getView() of BaseAdapter

Tags: android, baseadapter

So I have a custom adapter that extends BaseAdapter. And in the getView() function, I instantiate a handful of OnClickListeners to handle onClick events for views inside the list index (for the ListView). Here is an example:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<SomeObject> mObjectArray;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // ...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final SomeObject obj = mObjectArray.get(position);

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);

        TextView textView = TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.custom_text1);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textView.setText(obj.getText());
            }
        });

        // ...

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

It works fine, but I'm concerned if this is not recommended from performance standpoint? Is it better to have one OnClickListener for the CustomAdapter class and use TextView.setTag() and TextView.getTag() to customize it? Like below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // ...
    textView.setTag(obj);
    textView.setOnClickListener(oneOnClickListener);
    // ...
}

// ...

// One OnClickListener to handle all onClick events for textView
OnClickListener oneOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SomeObject obj = v.getTag();
        textView.setText(obj.getText());
    }
});
```

Or is instantiating new OnClickListener in getView() function considered OK? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't affect performance but your current adapter implementation is not efficient.  You need to only inflate the layout and get references to the subviews if `convertView == null` and also you should use the holder pattern.  [Here's an example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that and have implemented it. I omitted it from the above example code for simplicity, which is also why I omitted other things like a constructor and other required functions. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a problem to create anonymous `OnClickListeners` in `getView()`. `OnClickListener` is very lightweight after all. I do that actually quite often. I would only change that to the other method that you are mentioning if you experience concrete performance issues.